# Playa - Related Entries search post call fails

Tags: playa, relationships

In the related entries field, after typing a search term, a post call is made to return back a list of related entries that fit the search term. However, it is failing for us as you can see in the screen shot. I don't even get a 404 or 500. it just shows up as canceled. I have tested this on multiple machines and browsers and get the same result every time. Anyone have any ideas?

Link to screenshot => http://cl.ly/image/330V450W0j1h

~ C

Comment: What does the Console tab say in the inspector? One guess would be that your theme folders URL setting does not match the URL you're accessing the CP from, causing cross-domain issues (www vs non-www).